# how i can change the html code in multiple file of the website i have?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am write a two script tag in every page i have  in my project. I want to replace the script by the new script i have.

I create new page by copy paste of existing one so all code i write are same. I want to replace then they work (even not for all file) but most of files.

Can someone tell me how i can replace the code for all files(don't worry if it's not applies on some files.I will check them manually for replacing the code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Text Editor like 'Sublime Text 2'. 
Use Find>Find in Files
Enter your search criteria,
The location of the files
Replace (if you want to replace strings)

Click on Find

Answer (score 3):

[`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) might be appropriate for this:

```
$ sed -e 's/<script type="text\/javascript" src="my-old-script.js"><\/script>/<script type="text\/javascript" src="my-new-script.js"><\/script>/g' -i .bak *.html
```

That will replace every instance of:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-old-script.js"></script>
```

With:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-new-script.js"></script>
```

…in files in the current directory whose names end with `.html`, saving `.bak` files along the way in case it breaks something.